# The best way to load data in to Bootstrap Accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, optimization

I'm developing a website that will show a list with data from a database of installed computers around a company.

For now I'm just creating, through AJAX, the labels for each computer in the database by appending HTML code to a parent div as in the following screen:

[image]

On accordion toggle it will show more detailed data about each computer (there could be over 200 computers around there) the info will be shown as the following:

[image]

I need suggestions on how load the detailed data inside the accordion. Should I load through AJAX every time an accordion is opened (toggled) or should I create all the items inside the accordion on page load even if there could be over 200 computers?

I was going to append each time an accordion is triggered the HTML with all divs and other items that create the detailed view with data from AJAX but I would like know which is the best way to do it to get the best performance.

Comment: The most scalable way to achieve this would be to make an AJAX request for each individual accordion toggle.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan when the accordion is closed should i clear all the data i've created inside it?

Comment: That would depend on how often/quickly the information you have loaded becomes stale. Leaving it would give you better performance, but may mean that what's shown is no longer accurate.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i'd probably go for the way where i'd leave the data as the data in db will be out of date after 7 days if not updated

Comment: That sounds like a workable solution. 7 days is plenty of time. You'd need to do it the other way if the lifetime of the data was measured in minutes, not days.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Sorry, I've put it badly, i would say that the data will be out of date after 7 day but it can be updated every minute or hour (the new data is sent every time a pc will start)

Comment: That's right, but given the short lifecycle of a web page you can simply load the data once (when the accordion is toggled) and leave it in the DOM. Unless the page is left open for 7 days it will not be a problem. You seem to be overthinking this slightly :)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yeah probably i'm just overthinking it, thank you i've got the concept :)